# how can alexa recognize the email address and what should specify in alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm creating a sample skill i.e., user registration. In that i'm saving all values spelled by user. But the email address is not recognised by alexa. I created custom slot for email address.

```
      { 
       "name": "emailset", 
        "values": [ 
        { "id": null, 
          "name": { 
          "value": "aparna@gmail.com", 
           "synonyms": [] 
            } 
            } 
            ] 
            }
```

I created the custom slot "emailset" with the slot value "aparna@gmail.com". But Alexa didn't recognize the email address. Anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve user authentication/login you need to use the OAuth capabilities that the Amazon Echo has. The [Amazon documentation for setting up OAuth](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/link-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system.html) is quite extensive and gives a pretty good outline of what needs to be done.

This documentation isn't as step-by-step as some may like. In that case, here is a nice [step-by-step guide to setting up OAuth for an Alexa smart-home skill](https://www.whizzy.org/2016/12/howto-add-oauth-to-your-alexa-smart-home-skill-in-10-minutes/). If you aren't making a smart-home skill, it should still give you a nice overview of the process that you will need to go through.

I think overall Amazon wants to avoid having people develop their own authentication process like this. Having to say numbers and letters out-loud to your Alexa is a rather cumbersome process that goes against having a fluid voice interface and good UI design. Additionally, I have noticed with my Alexa development that the speech recognition of Alexa isn't robust enough to do e-mail authentication well and will just end up frustrating users.